# Unknown reason for PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm having a problem with simple PL/SQL here. I defined my table as follows:

```
TYPE tr_GatheredData IS RECORD(
BS_ID          number,
CUSTOMER_NAME  varchar2(200),
MONTH          varchar2(30),
YEAR           number,
LEAKAGE        number);

TYPE tt_GatheredData IS TABLE OF tr_GatheredData;
```

Afterwards I try to initiate a variable like this:

```
results := tt_GatheredData(1, 'lol', 'omg', 2, 3);
```

Everything seams to me to be correct, but I get

> Error(8,16): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TT_GATHEREDDATA'

on each compliation. Can you guys tell me where can the issiue be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle 18c [qualified expression](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/qualified-expressions-in-plsql-18c#qualified-expressions-with-record-types):

```
DECLARE
  TYPE tr_GatheredData IS RECORD(
     BS_ID          number,
     CUSTOMER_NAME  varchar2(200),
     MONTH          varchar2(30),
     YEAR           number,
     LEAKAGE        number);

  TYPE tt_GatheredData IS TABLE OF tr_GatheredData;
  results tt_GatheredData;
BEGIN
   results := tt_GatheredData(tr_GatheredData(1, 'lol', 'omg', 2, 3));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(results(1).Customer_name);
END;
//
```

Previous versions:

```
DECLARE
TYPE tr_GatheredData IS RECORD(
BS_ID          number,
CUSTOMER_NAME  varchar2(200),
MONTH          varchar2(30),
YEAR           number,
LEAKAGE        number);
TYPE tt_GatheredData IS TABLE OF tr_GatheredData;
  results tt_GatheredData;
  t tr_GatheredData ;
BEGIN
   t.BS_ID := 1;
   t.CUSTOMER_NAME := 'lol';
   t.MONTH := 'omg';
   t.YEAR := 2;
   t.LEAKAGE := 3;
   results := tt_GatheredData(t);  -- element has to be record type

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(results(1).Customer_name);
END;
//
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=926095412fef679aa616bd0c48219594)**

Comment: Or you can code your own constructor e.g. `new_GatheredData(bs_id etc) return tr_GatheredData`, though it tends not to be worth the effort unless it's going to be used multiple times. The 18c new feature is pretty cool though.

Answer (score 1):

`tt_GatheredData` is a collection of `tr_GatheredData` records, so you need to pass it a set of those, not `(1, 'lol', 'omg', 2, 3)`.

As Lukasz's answer mentioned, PL/SQL record types prior to Oracle 18c are just simple multi-value variables, so if you want a convenient constructor you have to write your own, or else declare each `tr_GatheredData` record and explicitly assign values to it.

Collection types do come with implicit constructors, or you can explicitly assign elements one at a time if you wanted to.

Here is one way, using a standalone (pre-18c) record constructor to build a collection with multiple elements in one shot:

```
declare
    type tr_GatheredData is record
    ( bs_id          number
    , customer_name  varchar2(200)
    , month          varchar2(30)
    , year           number
    , leakage        number );

    type tt_GatheredData is table of tr_GatheredData;
    results tt_GatheredData;

    function new_gathereddata
        ( p_bs_id          number
        , p_customer_name  varchar2
        , p_month          varchar2
        , p_year           number
        , p_leakage        number )
        return tr_GatheredData
    is
        r tr_GatheredData;
    begin
        r.bs_id          := p_bs_id;
        r.customer_name  := p_customer_name;
        r.month          := p_month;
        r.year           := p_year;
        r.leakage        := p_leakage;

        return r;
    end new_gathereddata;

begin
    results :=
        tt_GatheredData
        ( new_gathereddata(1, 'aaa', 'January',  1066, 10)
        , new_gathereddata(2, 'bbb', 'February', 1588, 15)
        , new_gathereddata(3, 'ccc', 'March',    1789, 20) );

    dbms_output.put_line('Collection contains ' || results.count || ' records.');
    dbms_output.put_line('results(3).year = ' || results(3).year);
end;
```

Output:

```
Collection contains 3 records.
results(3).year = 1789
```

Comment: Yes, helper function could be handy. Fortunately there is 18c so we don't need to write boilerplate code :)

Comment: Maybe one day. I really want private temp tables as well. At the moment we're on 12.1 and even 12.2 is a distant dream.